# Connecting nodes randomly with preferential attachment

Tags: python, networking, random, nodes

I am trying to make a network with preferential attachment. I will have 20 nodes in total and will begin with 1 node. Then, I will add the second node ( node2), and it will connect to node1. Then, the node3 will be added, and it can bind to node1 and node2 with equal probability because their degree of freedom is the same.. If node3 will bind to node2, the flat text will look like:

```
1 2 ( node1 connects with node2)
2 1 (node2 connects with node1, by default)
3 2 (node3 connects with node2)
2 3 (node2 connects with node3, by default)
```

And then, when I add node4, since node2 has more connections than the rest, node4 will prefer binding to node2, but it can also bind to node1 or node3. Here I am confused of how to make preferential attachment. I can randomly pair two lists,however, I cannot make them choose.
I have tried to make a weight list with probabilities, and then for each node, I tried to make a choice according to the probabilities. The code I tried to run:

```
from numpy.random import choice
import numpy as np, numpy.random
import itertools
#from tempfile import TemporaryFile
#make probabilities from 0 to 1 which will make 1 at the end
probab = np.random.dirichlet(np.ones(20),size=1)
a = probab.tolist()
merged = list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(a))
nodes = list(range(1,2001))
F = open("workfile.txt","w")

for node in nodes:

    Y = choice(nodes,p=merged)
    F.write(Y)
    print("done?")
```

I am not sure if it is the right way to do it, also I cannot run this code properly as it gives me an error of:

```
File "ex.py", line 33, in <module>
    np.savetxt('test.out', Y)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/numpy/lib/npyio.py", line 1175, in savetxt
    ncol = X.shape[1]
IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

Can give me some improvements about the method, and also how to fix this error?

Comment: What do you mean by `bind` what exactly are you trying to do? Do you have some code samples that you can share. I am not sure I understand the issue here.

Comment: Sorry I am still not clear. Is it just a matter of choosing two random numbers form a list of 20 numbers each time the code runs? for each of the node IDs

Comment: It is ,but there is more. For example, at the beginning the node1 and node2 are connected. Then, node3 is added and it randomly connects with node1. Then,node4 is added and it randomly connects with node1 too. And when node5 is added, it can bind to node1,2,3,4, however, since node1 has more connections than the others, node5 will prefer attaching to node1. But it can also bind to other nodes. It is very complicated..

Comment: Your description is confusing. First you say that node1 has two connections, but then you connect 4 other nodes to it. Please give a small complete example. And you should also post some code that attempts to do this, even if it doesn't work properly.

Comment: It was just an example ( node1 making connections with 4 nodes). I completely changed the description of the question including my approach. Hope this time would be more clear